# Average coinflips to reach the 6 (Custom game)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, game-theory, stochastic-analysis, infinite-games

a friend of mine asked me about a certain game mechanic in a videogame and how many tries it would take for him (on average) to reach his goal. In abstract form, it can be explained as follows:

- You start with the number 4
- The lowest you can go is 0
- Once you reach 6, you win
- You flip coins (50/50 distribution) one after another. If you get heads, you add 1 to your number, if it's tails, you subtract 1

-> How many tries will it take to reach 6?

My main problem is, that you have an unlimited number of tries and that there is actually an upper and lower bound on your "score".

Can someone help me out?

Comment: So if you reach $0$ do you stop (and never reach $6$), or do you keep flipping and stay at $0$ until you get heads and thereby go to $1$?

Comment: Yes. You can not lose. You have an infinite amount of tries. But it's in your favor, since you start at 4.

Comment: I don't think this question should have the `game-theory` tag. There is no strategic interaction whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Starting at position $4$, you have, in one flip, a fifty-fifty chance of going to position $3$ or position $5$.  So $E_4=1+\frac12 E_3+\frac12 E_5$ (where $E_k$ is the expected number of flips to get from position $k$ to the end of the game (position $6$)).  You can develop a bunch of equations like this and solve the resulting system using the fact that $E_6=0$.  Note: You have to be a bit careful with the equation for $E_0$ since you have a fifty-fifty chance of staying at $0$ or moving to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem very suited to be solved with a Monte Carlo simulation. Below is a simple code I used (Python), with $100,000$ simulations:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
def game():
    '''
    Defines the game.
    '''
    number = 4 # Starts at 4
    count = 0 # Counts the number of plays
    while not number == 6: # If the player is not at place 6 yet...
        number += 2*random.randint(0,1)-1 # Adds 1 or -1 with probability 1/2
        number = max(number, 0) # Guarantees we are not below 0
        count +=1 # Updates the counter
    return count # Returns the counter when the player arrives at 6
simulations = pd.Series([game() for i in range(100000)])
print(simulations.describe())
```

with output

```
count    100000.000000
mean         22.020540
std          30.137399
min           2.000000
25%           2.000000
50%           8.000000
75%          30.000000
max         383.000000
dtype: float64
```

Here's a histogram of the distribution:

[image]

Thus, the average number of tries is around 22. But notice that the median is around 8. Since the number of tries is unbounded by above, these outliers are bringing the mean up.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the method as described by @paw88789 and see if it matches the approximation as given by @econbernardo:

OK, so we get:

$E(0) = 1+ E(1)/2 + E(0)/2$

So: $E(0)/2=1+E(1)/2$

$E(1) = 1 + E(2)/2+E(0)/2 = 1 + E(2)/2+1+E(1)/2=2+E(2)/2+E(1)/2$

So: $E(1)/2=2 +E(2)/2$

Likewise (I'll save you the details), we get:

$E(2)/2=3 +E(3)/2$

$E(3)/2=4 +E(4)/2$

$E(4)/2=5 +E(5)/2$

$E(5)/2=6 +E(6)/2$

And since E(6)=0$, we thus get:

$E(5)/2=6 +0 = 6$, meaning that $E(5) = 12$

$E(4)/2=5 + 6= 11$, meaning that $E(4) = 22$

So yes, we got a match with @econbernardo empirical result!

and just to be complete:

$E(3)/2=4 +E(4)/2=4 + 11= 15$, meaning that $E(3) = 30$

$E(2)/2=3 +E(3)/2=3 + 15= 18$, meaning that $E(2) = 36$

$E(1)/2=2 +E(2)/2=2 + 18= 20$, meaning that $E(1) = 40$

$E(0)/2=1+E(1)/2= 1+20=21$, meaning that $E(0) = 42$

Comment: Good use of recursion in your derivation. Sadly, I believe the user who asked the question had his account deleted.

Comment: @econbernardo Huh!  I wonder what happened. Anyway, yes, it was nice to see that your empirical results matched the analytically derived result :)